# Is there a way to translate a matrix to an alternate scale?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, android-canvas

Let's say I start with an Bitmap that's 1000px x 1000px

I load it into a `SurfaceView` resident `Canvas` that displayed at some arbitrary (and depending on the device different) dimensions.

I can get those dimensions at runtime and measure the scale between them and the original (if I need that information at the end).

Then I allow the user to pinch/zoom/translate the image around the displayed canvas. All the while I have a `Matrix` which keeps track of, and is used to re-draw the image in its displayed screen region.

Subsequently this `Matrix`'s values all apply to the scaled space (and not the original 1000x1000 graphic).

So far so good - I have all this working.

However, when all is said and done, I'd like to apply this Matrix to the original Bitmap and save it out.  However, I'm at a loss as to how to modify all its internal values to apply it back to the unscaled original (1000x1000) size.

Curious if there's some auto-magical way to translate these or if I have to somehow apply each value based on the scale between the two sizes back to a new Matrix.

Comment: Orthogonal to your question, but possibly of use: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html

Comment: i assume you are using `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)` to draw on your `SurfaceView`, then use the same method when drawing on the temporary `Bitmap` and then save it out

Comment: @pskink, I am but you see - that will result in all the values being wrong! Let's say the user has moved the image 50px to the right (on the screen) - that translates to some different amount of positive motion on the X axis in what will be the final art because the 50 screen pixels is some proportion (larger or smaller) than the actual Bitmap. Hence my need to retranslate the entire Matrix back to the original dimensions (preserving the scaled user produced alterations)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, Do you want to take the screen image and transform that back to the the original (in which case y0u apply the inverse matrix) or do you want to take the original and apply the tranform so that it looks like the screen image but at a different destination?? then just use the same matrix

Comment: try `Matrix#mapRect` to see where your 1000x1000 rect will be mapped, then you can use `left` & `top` fields to retranslate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To invert a matrix**

matrix{ a,b,c,d,e,f } and the inverse is matrix { ia, ib, ic, id, ie, if }

```
    var cross =  a * d - b * c;
    ia = d / cross;
    ib = -b / cross;
    ic = -c / cross;
    id = a / cross;
    ie = (c * f - d * e) / cross;
    if = -(a * f - b * e) / cross;
```

Reverse the transform, the original from image coordinates to screen coordinates and the inverse matrix transforms screen coordinates to image coordinates.

If you have a transform on the screen and you want to know where on the image the top left of the screen is. Get the inverse transform and apply it to the screen coordinate (0,0) top left.

```
scrX = ?
scrY = ?
imageX = scrX  * ia + scrY * ic + ie;
imageY = scrX  * ib + scrY * id + if;
```

Comment: I'm tempted to think this actually answers my question, but I'm not sure that it does.  My `Matrix` applies to what is currently on the screen.  What I need to do is to translate it back to the original scale of the Bitmap being manipulated on-screen by the user. So, the original image is X by Y and on the screen it appears in whatever dimensions the screen allows and the 'Matrix` is relative to those screen dimensions. 
Does your solution apply to this scenario and if so, would you be so kind as to lay out the actual syntax for the Matrix transformation?

Comment: @GeniaS. If you want where on the image a screen coordinate is then yes. Eg if you want the image coordinates for a screen coordinates  where top/left (0,0),top/right(199,0),bottom/right (199,399) and bottom/left (0,299) then multiply each coordinate (as the second snippet shows) by the inverse transform and you will get the image coordinates for the of each corner this includes rotation, scaling, and translation. You will need access to the current transform (I have not used a android device so can not help you with code)

Comment: Thanks very much. Android is immaterial to the details. Indeed I need the displayed image (whatever its display dimensions are) to map back to the original Bitmap rectangle but preserve the rotation/translation/scaling that was applied to the displayed element. I'll have to make sure that the Matrix class in Android maps its a,b,c,d etc. to the array you outline in your solution - or can you confirm that it does?